# Log scale on bar plot brake axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a the following bar plot with ggplot:

```
df  %>% ggplot( aes(x= group,y= cases,fill=color   ) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

The issue is that the smaller colors are not visible, hence I tried to use a log scale:

```
df  %>% ggplot( aes(x= group,y= cases,fill=color   ) ) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = comma) +  
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

But this completelly broke the scales, now I´m getting a 10 MM value from nowhere and bar sizes are wrong

The data I´m ussing for this is the following:

```
index,group,color,cases
1,4,4,9
2,4,3,61
3,1,1,5000
4,4,2,138
5,4,1,246
6,3,1,359
7,2,1,2000
8,3,2,57
9,1,2,153
10,2,2,130
11,2,3,15
12,1,3,23
13,3,3,11
14,2,4,1
```

Comment: When you are stacking a bar chart with a logarithmic scale you are solving this math problem: log(a) + log(b) + log(c) =log(a*b*c)  thus your 10 million values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: You cannot and should not use a log scale with a stacked barplot.  If you want to use a log scale, use a "dodged" barplot instead.  You'll also have better luck to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` here and set your `fill=` variable as a factor.

**Geom_col vs. geom_bar**

Try using `geom_col` in place of `geom_bar`.  You can use `coord_flip()` if the direction is not to your liking.  [See here for reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html), but the gist of the issue is that `geom_bar` should be used when you want to plot against "count", and `geom_col` should be used when you want to plot against "values".  Here, your y-axis is "cases" (a value), so use `geom_col`.

**The Problem with log scales and Stacked Barplots**

With that being said, [u/Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e) is absolutely correct.  The plot you are getting makes sense, because the underlying math being done to calculate the y-axis values is: `log10(x) + log10(y) + log10(z)` instead of what you expected, which was `log10(x + y + z)`.

Let's use the numbers in your actual data frame for comparison here.  In "group 1", you have the following:

```
index group color cases
    3     1     1  5000
    9     1     2   153
   12     1     3    23
```

So on the y-axis what's happening is the total value of a *stacked barplot* (without a log scale) will be the sum of all.  In other words:

```
> 5000 + 153 + 23
[1] 5176
```

This means that each of the bars represents the correct relative size, and when you add them up (or *stack* them up), the total size of the bar is equivalent to the total sum.  Makes sense.

Now consider the same case, but for a *log10 scale*:

```
> log10(5000) + log10(153) + log10(23)
[1] 7.245389
```

Or, just about 17.5 million.  The total height of the bar is still the sum of all individual bars (because that's what a stacked barplot is), and you can still compare the relative sizes, but *the sum total of the individual logs does not equal the log of the sum*:

```
>log10(5000 + 153 + 23)
[1] 3.713994
```

**Suggested Way to Change your Plot**

Moral of the story: you can still use a log scale to "stretch out" the small bars, but don't stack them.  Use `postion='dodge'`:

```
df  %>% ggplot( aes(x= group,y= log10(cases),fill=as.factor(color)   ) ) + 
    geom_col(position='dodge') + 
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Finally, `position='dodge'` (or `position=position_dodge(width=...)`) does not work with `fill=color`, since `df$color` is not a factor (it's numeric).  This is also why your legend is showing a gradient for a categorical variable.  That's why I used `as.factor(color)` in the `ggplot` call here, although you can also just apply that to the original dataset with `df$color <- as.factor(df$color)` and do the same thing.

Comment: I´m getting the same result. The dataset I´m using is in the question at the end.

Comment: You're right - take u/Dave2e's comment to heart here, because the moral of the story is to not use log scale with STACKED barplots: use a dodged plot instead.  You should be switching to `geom_col` and also need to set your `fill=` aesthetic as a factor for proper formatting.  See the edits made to the answer, which should now be quite complete.